# How can I prove that a Markov Chain is reversible with only few informations?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I would like to prove that a markov chain is reversible, I don't have the transition matrix but I know that it is stochastic (even doubly stochastic), irreducible, aperiodic and symmetrical, but I am not sure how to prove it.
Can someone help me?

Comment: The detailed balance equations themselves read $\pi_i p_{ij}=\pi_j p_{ji}$ for all $i,j$. Due to symmetry, this forces $\pi_j=\pi_j$ for all $i,j$ with the property $p_{ij}>0$ (because in this case you can divide through by it). Since you also have irreducibility, this property propagates out to requiring $\pi_i=\pi_j$ for all $i,j$ (regardless of whether they are directly connected). So the candidate for a reversibility distribution is the uniform distribution.

Comment: Another way to run the argument is that double stochasticity -> the uniform distribution is invariant and then symmetry -> the uniform distribution is reversible. Notably if you go this way you see that you didn't need the irreducibility at all, except to rule out the possibility of some other reversibility distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the transition matrix is doubly stochastic and irreducible, the stationary distribution is uniquely given by the uniform distribution on the states, i.e. $ \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{1}$ if written as a probability vector where $n = |S|$ and $\mathbf{1}$ is the vector with only $1$ as entry. The Markov chain therefore satisfies the detailed balance equations, as by symmetry $p_{i,j} = p_{j,i} \implies \frac{1}{n} p_{i,j} = \frac{1}{n} p_{j,i}$ holds for all $i,j \in S$.
Therefore, the Markov chain is reversible.